# Looping in R done automatically

Tags: r

I am trying to write a loop in R for the following. I have a dataframe df

```
Reads Counts
aaa     1
bbb     20
ccc     3
```

and so on. I want to get a dataframe which counts the number of reads that are less than or equal to a certain value of count. Example there are 3 reads with Counts <= 100 and 2 reads with counts <=10. Expected Output

```
Counts number_reads
100     3
10      2
1       1
```

and so on. Right now I am doing it manually with

```
nrow(df[which(df$Counts<=100),])
```

and so on. Can you suggest an edit where I can get the expected output automatically for counts incremented say in steps of 10 (100, 90, 80 etc). Thanks

Comment: May be you need `cut` with `table` i.e. `table(cut(df$Counts , breaks=seq(10,100, by=10)))`

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. Can I plot the result of table in some way?

Comment: `plot(..a table...)` works for that

Answer (score 4):

In statistics, the frequency of X less than a threshold is called the *empirical cumulative distribution function*: ecdf for short.

In your case, you need to scale up by n to convert the frequency to counts.

Using the sleep data:

```
> nrow(sleep) * ecdf(sleep$extra)(5:-2)
[1] 19 17 14 14 10  6  2  0
```

which says there are 19 cases where extra is less than 5, 17 less than 4, and so on.

In your case, you might have

```
nrow(df) * ecdf(df$Counts)(c(100,10,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

`cut` puts values into bins. `table` counts those values. `cumsum` will give you the cumulative sum up to the desired level.

```
> Counts <- c(1, 20, 3)
> cut(Counts, c(0, 10, 100)) ## Or, I guess, cut(Counts, c(0, 1, 10, 100)
[1] (0,10]   (10,100] (0,10]  
Levels: (0,10] (10,100]
> table(cut(Counts, c(0, 10, 100)))

  (0,10] (10,100] 
       2        1 
> cumsum(table(cut(Counts, c(0, 10, 100))))
  (0,10] (10,100] 
       2        3
```

Change the second argument to `cut` to match the breaks you are interested in.

---

Similar to `cut` would be `findInterval`.